# CV2 Distance with projectPoints

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, aruco

is it possible to calculate the distance between points which i created with cv2.projectPoints?

I have two aruco markers and from both markers i have created (with cv2.projectPoints) points which are in a specific distance to the marker. Now i want to know how far these points are away from each other?

I know you cant give a specific code without an MVP and it is not necessary i only need an idea how this is possible to calculate. I would be awesome if someone knows maybe a cv2 function or a way to calculate these?

Thank you very much <3

[image]

Edit:

I generated the four identity matrixes and inversed all of them. Code and result ist below.

```py
#T_point1_marker1 = np.linalg.inv(T_marker1_point1)
#T_marker1_cam = np.linalg.inv(T_cam_marker1)

T_point1_marker1 = np.array([
    [ 1.,  0.,  0., -0.1 ],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0., -0.05],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.  ],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.  ],
])

T_marker1_cam = np.array([
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.10809129],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.03833054],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1., -0.35931477],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.        ],
])

T_cam_marker2 = np.array([
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.09360527],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0., -0.01229168],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.36470099],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.        ],
])

T_marker2_point2 = np.array([
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.005],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.1  ],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.   ],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.   ],
])
#Process finished with exit code 1
```

The think i don't understand is this part:

`T_point1_point2 = T_point1_marker1 @ T_marker1_cam @ T_cam_marker2 @ T_marker2_point2`

How do i bring these four matrixes together so i get `T_point1_point2`?
Thanks again :)

Comment: If you have the (X,Y) pixel coordinates, and you know the resolution in pixels-per-millimeter, then it's a simple division.  I think you do know the resolution, if you placed those two points so precisely from the center of the marker.

Comment: What's the length of the blue line in pixels? What's the 5mm, 10 mm, 20mm and 50mm in pixels?

Comment: stuffing a bunch of translation vectors into a matrix is generally not useful.

Comment: I edited it again. Guess i understood something wrong at the first try. 

Hopefully you have a moment to look at it again :)

Comment: ah, those matrices look better. the part you "don't understand" is perhaps so simple that it spooks you. that line is literally just a line of python code. the result of it is `T_point1_point2[0:3,3] == np.array([0.1067 , 0.07604, 0.00539])` (assuming all the translations are ok)

Comment: since you seem to actually be detecting and pose-recovering those markers from a camera picture, you should use not just the translation but the entire pose (including rvec). you'll need `Rodrigues` to turn the rvec into a 3x3 matrix. that's the top left part of a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: yeah but how do i get T_point1_point2? Just add them all together?

T_point1_point2 = T_point1_marker1 + T_marker1_cam + T_cam_marker2 + T_marker2_point2

Comment: And is the rvec really neccessary? You are right the camera is mounted on my head and films my hands. For the question i simplifyed the task normally one marker is flexible and the other is fixed. So i need from every frame the distance between the two points. But its always just points and the distance between them is the only information i need. Thanks again and sry for my "stupid" questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248065/discussion-between-major23-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Comment: this is no longer one question but a discussion with unbounded scope creep. it is unreasonable ask anyone to spend any more time on this.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/calibrated-camera-distance-between-two-projected-points/10241

Comment: Thanks but i still dont get the line: T_point1_point2 = T_point1_marker1 @ T_marker1_cam @ T_cam_marker2 @ T_marker2_point2

What did you calculate to get this: T_point1_point2[0:3,3] == np.array([0.1067 , 0.07604, 0.00539])

Answer (score 0):

Since your graphic contains measurements of physical distance, rather than pixels, I'll assume you're asking about *3D*, i.e. you want a 3D distance between those points...

You just need to define the poses of those points, relative to their markers. That is `T_marker1_point1` and `T_marker2_point2`. Make those be pure translation, probably with Z=0 if these points are in each respective marker's plane. Literally make a 4x4 identity matrix, then stick your nominal (constructed) dimensions into the last column.

Then you need the marker poses relative to the camera, `T_cam_marker1` and `T_cam_marker2`.

Finally you calculate

```py
T_point1_point2 = T_point1_marker1 @ T_marker1_cam @ T_cam_marker2 @ T_marker2_point2
# where
# T_marker1_cam = np.linalg.inv(T_cam_marker1)
# and so on
```

The translation part of that pose matrix gives you the distance between those points. You can ignore the rotation component. That'd only give you the rotation between those markers, because your points were defined as poses of the same orientation as their respective markers. Yes, orientation is silly for points but eh...

All of that is 4x4 matrices. Compose from `tvec`, put in third column, and `rvec`, turned into a 3x3 rotation matrix using `cv.Rodrigues`. Decompose 4x4 matrix into rvec and tvec accordingly (Rodrigues goes both ways).

Comment: Oh wow that was a big help. I added some more informations at the first post. Maybe you have a second to look at it.